# error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:3483: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function cv::resize

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

I have a error as mentioned in the question in the below code for resize function of cv2. I have referred here
[error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172770/error-215-ssize-width-0-ssize-height-0-in-function-resize)

But I think the image is correctly loaded. So I would appreciate some help.

```
for rect in rects:
        # Draw the rectangles
        cv2.rectangle(im, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3) 
        # Make the rectangular region around the digit
        leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
        pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
        pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
        roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]
        print(roi.shape)
        # Resize the image
        roi = cv2.resize(roi, None, fx=28, fy=28, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))
        # Calculate the HOG features
        roi_hog_fd = hog(roi, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
        roi_hog_fd = pp.transform(np.array([roi_hog_fd], 'float64'))
        nbr = clf.predict(roi_hog_fd)
        cv2.putText(im, str(int(nbr[0])), (rect[0], rect[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)
```

Comment: what does `print(roi.shape)` prints before the error?

Comment: It gives (128,0)

Comment: So your image has a 0 dimension, you can't resize it. be sure that `leng` is at least 1.

Comment: Oh, actually, my original image which I read using cv2.imread() is of size (546, 768).

Comment: but you're resizing `roi`, not your original image

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're doing some kind of detection, and the result you get is `rects`. I also got the problem you had when one `rect` goes beyond the boundaries.

In my case, I found the 4 coordinators of the rect `startX, startY, endX, endY` and then checked if they're out of the boundaries.

`if (startX<0 or startY<0 or endX > W or endY > H):
     break`

Hope it can solve your problem.