# scene classification, unable to load images in my image processing exercice

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, os.path

Hi in this code I'am unnable to load my own images in the directory /datasets/training, but i do can load /datasets/animals. Why is that?

I'm using OS Windows, and someone told me that the path isn't correct but i dont seem to understand, I'm in the dark and need some help here, thanks in advance!

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import os

def image_to_feature_vector(image, size=(32, 32)):
# resize the image to a fixed size, then flatten the image into
# a list of raw pixel intensities
    return cv2.resize(image, size).flatten()
def extract_color_histogram(image, bins=(8, 8, 8)):
# extract a 3D color histogram from the HSV color space using
# the supplied number of `bins` per channel
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [0, 1, 2], None, bins,
                    [0, 180, 0, 256, 0, 256])
# handle normalizing the histogram if we are using OpenCV 2.4.X
    if imutils.is_cv2():
    hist = cv2.normalize(hist)
# otherwise, perform "in place" normalization in OpenCV 3 (I
# personally hate the way this is done
    else:
        cv2.normalize(hist, hist)
# return the flattened histogram as the feature vector
    return hist.flatten()

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
            help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-k", "--neighbors", type=int, default=1,
            help="# of nearest neighbors for classification")
ap.add_argument("-j", "--jobs", type=int, default=-1,
            help="# of jobs for k-NN distance (-1 uses all available cores)")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
print("[INFO] describing images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))

for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
# load the image and extract the class label (assuming that our
# path as the format: /path/to/dataset/{class}.{image_num}.jpg
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split("_")[0]

pixels = image_to_feature_vector(image)
hist = extract_color_histogram(image)

# update the raw images, features, and labels matricies,
# respectively
rawImages.append(pixels)
features.append(hist)
labels.append(label)

# show an update every 1,000 images
if i > 0 and i % 1000 == 0:
    print("[INFO] processed {}/{}".format(i, len(imagePaths)))

# show some information on the memory consumed by the raw images
# matrix and features matrix
rawImages = np.array(rawImages)
features = np.array(features)
labels = np.array(labels)
print("[INFO] pixels matrix: {:.2f}MB".format(
rawImages.nbytes / (1024 * 1000.0)))
print("[INFO] features matrix: {:.2f}MB".format(
features.nbytes / (1024 * 1000.0)))

# partition the data into training and testing splits, using 75%
# of the data for training and the remaining 25% for testing
(trainRI, testRI, trainRL, testRL) = train_test_split(
rawImages, labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
(trainFeat, testFeat, trainLabels, testLabels) = train_test_split(
features, labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# train and evaluate a k-NN classifer on the raw pixel intensities
print("[INFO] evaluating raw pixel accuracy...")
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=args["neighbors"],
                         n_jobs=args["jobs"])
model.fit(trainRI, trainRL)
acc = model.score(testRI, testRL)
print("[INFO] raw pixel accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(acc * 100))

# train and evaluate a k-NN classifer on the histogram
# representations
print("[INFO] evaluating histogram accuracy...")
model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=args["neighbors"],
                         n_jobs=args["jobs"])
model.fit(trainFeat, trainLabels)
acc = model.score(testFeat, testLabels)
print("[INFO] histogram accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(acc * 100))
```

I really hope someone could make it clear.
thanks.

Comment: can you post the error too.

Comment: This is the error:
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0) in cv::resize, file C:\bld\opencv_1520732670222\work\opencv-3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp, line 4044
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "knn_classifier_loan.py", line 71, in <module>
    pixels = image_to_feature_vector(image)
  File "knn_classifier_loan.py", line 18, in image_to_feature_vector
    return cv2.resize(image, size).flatten()
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) 3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function cv::resize

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172770/error-215-ssize-width-0-ssize-height-0-in-function-resize this may be helpful

Comment: Ok, @Krishna please if you could spare a little bit of your time...pls help me.

Comment: sorry for late reply. loading image should not be a great problem. try passing absolute path as an argument and see whether it works or not, then try to narrow down the error layer by layer.